# \vspace not working as expected

Tags: spacing, captions, mdframed, minted

I have a code block using minted and mdframed and a caption afterwards.

```
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{minted}[tabsize=4]{c++}
    some code
\end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
\begingroup\captionof{listing}{some caption\label{lst:label}}\endgroup
```

The caption however is too far away from the code.
I tried adding negative vertical space right after the frame, however it doesn't work correctly.
Up to `\vspace{-4em}` nothing happens, but with `\vspace{-5em}`, the caption is moved right into the code block.

How can I move the caption that it is positioned right after the code block?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174587/mdframed-vertical-space-difference).

When I use `\unskip` after the frame, the caption will be positioned right after it. `\vspace` also works now, but is not needed anymore, at least for my case.